# A boy is kidnapped by space pirates and forced to be in their crew

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for help identifying a science fiction book that I read about 20 years ago - to do with space piracy.

A young man is kidnapped on his world and forced into being part of a pirate crew on a space ship.

Details I can remember: -

1. The young man carries a Walther PP or PPK pistol constructed in his parents forge or foundry.
2. The space ships have 'sails' that need to be set and reefed like a normal sailing ship.
3. At one stage the young man is lost overboard and feared lost - until he returns and is considered a ghost.

The book started with a rather graphic torture scene - but I cannot remember how that fits in with the rest of the story.

I do remember that the cover showed a barrel shaped space ship with sails depicting a skull and crossbones.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25615226-arabella-of-mars

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2806912-annals-of-klepsis

Comment: https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/winds-of-khalakovo-bradley-p-beaulieu/1100088413?ean=9781597802185

Answer (score 23):

**HENRY MARTYN by L. Neil Smith**

I haven't got around to read this book yet, but from what I know of it, this is almost certainly the one you're looking for. It has a boy kidnapped by pirates, opens with a torture scene, and the space pirate ship has sails.

[image]

From a [review on Tor.com](https://www.tor.com/2020/12/03/pirates-in-space-henry-martyn-by-l-neil-smith/):

> The book opens as a young Henry Martyn is tortured into revealing everything he knows about his home planet, and then tortured to death for the entertainment of an unnamed evil villain

> The discovery of something called §-physics has transformed industry and technology, permitting spaceships to neutralize inertia, enclose themselves in a breathable atmosphere, and spread sails made out of §-fields to catch the tachyon winds and move faster than light. Fighting is done using thrustibles on a personal level and projectibles between ships, weapons that both create a concussive force for attack, and a protective field for defense.

> But after [the protagonist] distinguishes himself in battle with a corsair, going overboard to sabotage the enemy vessel, the captain leaves him drifting in space.

Comment: Yarrr! This be a fine find, Jim lad.

Comment: Presumably this is related to the song, one of the Child Ballads and famously recorded by Joan Baez: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Martin_(song).  In the song three brothers draw lots to determine which one would turn robber, all on the salt sea, the salt sea...

Comment: Yes - Henry Martyn by L. Neil Smith - thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @Stephen please click the checkmark next to this answer to indicate it is correct.